# Disable LI being clicked if form has not been submitted

Tags: jquery, menu, alert, prompt

I need away to disable a LI menu item/s if a form has not been submitted. and if the user tries to click on the li I want an alert to show or even a promt to tell the users or offer the user the following options

```
alert("We are sorry as this is a new business lead, you need to save the information first.");
```

or

```
promt("we understand that you want to continue, please click ok for us to save the information you have inputted");
```

Answer (score 0):

Lots of ways to do it, try:

```
$.ajax({
   ...
   beforeSend: function() {
       if (isMyFormSubmitted()) {
           $('li').click(function() {
               alert('...');
           });
       } else {
           $('li').click(function() {
               prompt('...');
           });    
       }
   }
});
```

`isMyFormSubmitted()` is some function that returns true or false depending on if the form has been submitted yet.  Obviously you have to run through all the fields to see if anything has changed in that function.